# check if string start with some string and ending in a digit - sh script

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I want to check if some variable is starting with some string (A-) and ending with digit in shell script.

My script (test.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash

VAR=A-1

if [[ $VAR =~ A-*[0-9 ] ]]; then
        echo "yes"
else
        echo "no"
fi
```

The error I get after running `sh test.sh`:

`test.sh: 5: test.sh: [[: not found`

I tried to change the concession to:
`if [ $VAR =~ A-*[0-9 ] ]; then`
and got this error: `test.sh: 5: [: A-1: unexpected operator`

Comment: Bash provides many features not available in POSIX shell `[sh]` that are relevant to answering this question. Please specify which you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variables should always be quoted:
`VAR="A-1"`

The issue in your code is with the `space in the square brackets: [...]` which you've defined in the regex: `[0-9 ]`.
There shouldn't be any space within it.

The correct code to check if some variable is starting with `A-` and ending with `digit` should be :

```
#!/bin/bash

VAR="A-1"

if [[ "$VAR" =~ ^A-.*[0-9]$ ]]; then
        echo "yes"
else
        echo "no"
fi
```

Please note the `double quotes` around the variable `VAR`.

As per the OP's comments, it looks like `sh` is being used instead `bash` , as the regex matching operator : `=~` doesn't work in `sh` and is `bash` specific.

Updated code using `sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

VAR="A-1"

if echo "$VAR"| grep -Eq "^A-.*[0-9]$"
  then
    echo "Yes"
else
    echo "no"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still got the same error. Also, If the VAR need to start with "A-" what will the syntax?

Comment: Can you show us the output of `echo $SHELL`? for the `VAR` to start with "A-", you can use : `"$VAR" =~ ^A-.*[0-9]$` inside `if` condition.

Comment: Thanks! But I still get the same error. It look like it doesn't recognize the "=~" condition .

Comment: @yiaca: can you check my updated answer using `sh` and let me know if it works?

Comment: @yiaca: Glad it worked! If you find this answer useful, you can accept this answer as well :-)

Answer (score 1):

The regex to match a string which `starts with A- and ends with a digit`
should be: `^A-.*[0-9]$` or more strictly `^A-.*[[:digit:]]$`.
Then please modify your scpipt as:

```
#!/bin/bash

VAR="A-1"

if [[ $VAR =~ ^A-.*[0-9]$ ]]; then
    echo "yes"
else
    echo "no"
fi
```

Then invoke it with `bash test.sh`, not with `sh test.sh`.

Comment: You would think out of 4 answers, the first 3 would have come up with this... but nope...

Answer (score 0):

`sh test.sh` does not use `bash` to run the script, it uses `sh`, which, depending on the system, may not have the same capabilities as bash.

You can use:

```
bash test.sh
```

Or:

```
chmod a+rx test.sh # one time only
./test.sh          # your script is set to use /bin/bash in the #! line.
```

Comment: I tried ```chmod a+rx test.sh``` and got the same error. I looking for the syntax for ``sh``` cmd and mot ```bash```

Comment: Indeed.  I got a different error.  You need to put double quotes around your regular expression.

Comment: You should ask separate questions about (a) why your shell script is not running properly (which is what you asked and what I addressed) and (b) how to get the regular expression to work properly (which is what your title is asking).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like : ${VAR:${#VAR}-1:1}

Cf. https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/bash-shell-parameter-substitution-2.html

```
[[ "${VAR:${#VAR}-1:1}" =~ [0-9] ]] && echo yes
```